# Failing hard drive, want to replace with SSD

Tags: ssd, upgrade, computer-building

I have a hard drive that appears to be failing. It is a normal SATA based hard disk that I am looking to replace with a Solid State Drive but I have a few questions.

1. I have a motherboard that is a few years old. It is an ASUS Rampage Formula. I can't find my old manual but I think it is a SATA 3gbps? Is that SATA 2?
2. It seems that all of the SSD that are on newegg are 2.5". I believe my case only has slots for 3.5" drives. Do they make something that I could put in a 2.5" drive into a 3.5" slot? Any recommendations on that?
3. If I buy a SATA 3 drive but my motherboard is only SATA 2, will it still work? Does it just "downgrade" the speed to the one below?

Comment: The answers to 1, 2, and 3 are all "yes". As for 4, we don't do product recommendations.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You should have answered... you still should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes.  [SATA 2.0 is 3Gbit/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_.28SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs.29)
2. Yes.  [Newegg has many](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=43&name=HDD-Accessories)
3. Yes.  [Read the last sentence in this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_.28SATA_6_Gbit.2Fs.29).
4. As has been pointed out, SU doesn't do product recommendations.  There are multiple sites out there reviewing SSDs.  [Here is one of them](http://thessdreview.com/).